# Math riddle that 4 of us can't solve.

Tags: puzzle

The riddle:  How can 8+9+10=7. Our idea is that 8,9,10 is in a number base different from the number base that the answer 7 is in.  We have tried several bases but can't find the answer. Any other idea is also welcomed.

Comment: If this is one of those "move a line to make this equation true" riddles then you could also move the 1 in front of the 10 to make $8+9+0=17$

Comment: Is it worth noting that $8+9-10=7$ ? Or $\lfloor \frac{8 . 9}{10}\rfloor = 7$

Comment: Let's define $x\oplus y=\frac{x+y}{-1}$ then $8\oplus 9\oplus 10=7$

Answer (score 1):

It could be if you take addition modulo $10$. And if we are trying to find all modulo that works we have to solve $27 \equiv _n 7$ we get $n\mid 20$ and $n>7$. So the only modulo that works are $10$ and $20$.

Comment: with modulo 20 too

Comment: Modulo $2$  and modulo $5$ also work.